# Importing a CSV data of tree format and displaying on the already created tree structure using NodeJs and JavaScript

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, lazy-loading, jstree

I have created a **sample tree** with two nodes and that can be found at github

[https://github.com/vbudithi/Creating-a-sample-tree-using-HTML-Javascript-and-Jquery](https://github.com/vbudithi/Creating-a-sample-tree-using-HTML-Javascript-and-Jquery.)

I used `jsTree` plugin for my project to create a tree

Even though i didn't create for infinite nodes, I need solution for infinite nodes.

I want to import CSV file which contains data in tree structure. When I upload the CSV file, the CSV file in tree format should automatically gets uploaded in to the parent node and child nodes of a tree structure which i have created.

For eg: If my CSV file has a tree format of

```
Andy
    Mandy
         Candy
              Pandy
                   Sandy
```

The CSV file after uploading should display in the tree structure .

Can i get code for `NodeJS` and `JavaScript`?

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**